# Should I specify parameters when renaming a command?

Tags: macros

For the sake of having semantic code, I wanted to define a command `\closure` that has the same effect as `\overline`. Initially, I thought the simplest way to achieve this would be:

```
\newcommand{\closure}[1]{\overline{#1}}
```

But, then I experimented with taking out the use of a parameter in my definition, and I found I could just write:

```
\newcommand{\closure}{\overline}
```

Both ways of defining `\closure` seem to work. So, I have two questions: (a) Is there any difference between the first and second definitions? And, if not, (b) Is one way more "correct" than the other?

Comment: You can simply do `\let\closure\overline` and then use `\closure{...}`. What you want to do is just change the name of the macro. And you are always giving an argument.

Comment: @HarishKumar But that will not check that `\closure` is not already defined. `\newcommand` is safer .

Comment: I'm not sure it matters technically. But I think it is generally better to specify the parameters because it makes the syntax required to use the command immediately apparent. With `\newcommand\closure{\outline}`, it is not obvious - just from the definition - that the command requires an argument. `\newcommand\closure[1]...` makes that clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Full form

```
\newcommand{\closure}[1]{\overline{#1}}
```

`\overline` does not like `\par`. It throws the error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

Therefore, it makes sense to include the restriction to `\closure` by using non-`\long` arguments:

```
\newcommand*{\closure}[1]{\overline{#1}}
```

Now the error message is:

```
Runaway argument?
{...
! Paragraph ended before \closure was complete.
```

Much clearer for the user.

*Advantages:*

- Definition is easy to understand.
- If the argument must not be `\long` (no `\par` tokens allowed), the command should be defined as not `\long` by the star form of `\newcommand`. Then the error message is more user-friendly, showing the error for the higher level command.

*Disadvantage:*

- Small run-time penalty.

### Without arguments

```
\newcommand{\closure}{\overline}
\newcommand*{\closure}{\overline}
```

Star or non-star form does not matter usually, because the macro does not have arguments.

*Advantage:*

- Efficient.

*Disadvantage:*

- Errors are shown for `\overline`, but the user has used `\closure`.

### `\let` form

```
\let\closure\overline
```

This can be used, if `\overline` will not change. Otherwise `\closure` will hae the meaning of `\overline` at definition time.

*Advantage:*

- Most efficient.

*Disadvantages:*

- Sometimes `\let` is not enough. For example, macros with optional arguments or robust macros via `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Internally these macros define another macro with a small modification of the base name (e.g., name with appended space as part of the name). This is not caught by a simple `\let`.
  Package `letltxmacro` with `\LetLtxMacro` helps in these cases.
- The underlying command should not change, otherwise the macro defined by `\let` will still have the old meaning.
- If the command is already defined, `\let` will overwrite it without warning. This can be fixed by:

  ```
  \newcommand{\closure}{}% throws an error, if \closure is defined
  \let\closure\overline
  ```